# How to use different network policies for administrative logins and wireless users?

Tags: cisco, radius, nps

I'm using a RADIUS server (NPS on Windows 2008 R2) to centrally manage authentication for a bunch of Cisco devices, including switches and wireless access points; I'm currently using RADIUS to authenticate IOS console/SSH logins, and provide administrative access to those devices to Active Directory users.

I'm planning to implement RADIUS/AD authentication for wireless users, too; the focus of this question is *not* how to do this, but a different problem: how can I apply different NPS policies to users accessing IOS for administrative duties, and to users accessing wireless access points? What RADIUS attributes can I filter on in order to distinguish a IOS login from a wireless login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RADIUS attribute to filter on is "NAS-Port-Type" (attribute 61); the relevant values are:

- Administrative access:

  - Async (0) (for console access
  - Virtual (5) (for Telnet/SSH access
- Wireless access:

  - Wireless - IEEE 802.11 (19)
  - Wireless - Other (18)

Source: http://www.iana.org/assignments/radius-types/radius-types.xml#radius-types-13